# What is скорбну from a grammatical viewpoint?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

In [Сонет](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD)) by Pushkin, we have this verse:

> Им скорбну мысль Камоэнс облекал

Why do we have скорбну and not скобную? I don't understand what скорбну is from a grammatical viewpoint.

Comment: That's https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Краткая_форма_прилагательных

Comment: @alamar Your link says: "Качественные прилагательные могут иметь не только атрибутивные (полные), но и предикативные (краткие) формы" and "Предика́т (лат. praedicatum «заявленное, упомянутое, сказанное») — это утверждение, высказанное о субъекте." but, here, смысль is not a субъект and, by the way, that's why https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/скорбный does not give the form скорбну, which would be a краткая форма in the accusative, while a predicate should be in the nominative case.

Comment: Wiktionary does not list declensions for short forms of adjectives, but they are declensed, and indeed it is in accusative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the short form of the adjective in the accusative.

It answers the question `какову мысль? скорбну.`

It is a rare word in modern Russian but valid when this adjective takes the place of a verb, and always valid in poetry.

You can look them up using [ruscorpora](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CskBEqUBCqIBChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxJyChkKA2xleBISChDRgdC60L7RgNCx0L3Ri9C5CgoKBGZvcm0SAgoACg8KBWdyYW1tEgYKBGJyZXYKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoAKhgKCAgAEAoYMiAKEAUgAEAFagQwLjk1eAAyAggBOgEBMAE=) if you use the grammatical qualifier `brev`.

Answer (score 1):

The link to the national corpus of the Russian language provided by Alamar gives 135 examples and only one of them corresponds to your question.

> 119. П. И. Мельников-Печерский. В лесах. Книга первая (1871-1874)
>      "Я кляну да свою буйну́ головушку, Я корю свое печально скорбно сердечушко!"

But this example immediately reminds us of many similar phrases from the Russian epic.

> Что, Иван-царевич, невесел, буйну голову повесил

> смотрит он на красну девицу

> взяли молодца за белы рученьки

> закрыл он ясны оченьки

> выпил зелена вина

Alas, I'm not a linguist or a philologist, so I can't say whether it's called the ancient Russian language or the poetic language or something else. Perhaps one of the experts will clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think you should be more precise about where the citations are taken from because "the Russian epic" is a bit too vague to me and my knowledge of Russian literature before Pushkin is almost null.

Comment: These are phrases from Russian medieval ballads and fairy tales. The fact is that the poetic language of the Russian epic is characterized by stable combinations of "adjective + noun". The *девица* is always *красная,*  the *молодец* is always  *добрый,* etc. So these are not quotes from any particular work, these are phrases that are repeated in many ballads and fairy tales.Now I remember another song from the XVII century "и сорвали **чёрну** шапку с моей буйной головы".